# How to conditionally transform signInName claim in Azure B2C custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a requirement to be able to login to azure B2C with both email and phone number with a regular password (not OTP). I do not want to use OTP SMS as I need two factor login and OTP is a second factor.

I thought I would be able to achieve this based on username-or-email example. I want to have a phone number as a userName. I have resolved a signup case, however I'm focusing on sign in. Is there any option to transform signInName using [StringReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#stringreplace) after singInName is collected and before it is send for verification?

I have tried to set up a technical profile which would transform user name from:
7900 654321 to 7900654321 (Replace space with empty string). I tried to achieve that with following policy:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="regexAnalysisUsername" />

        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="NormalizePhoneNumberProfile"
            ContinueOnError="false">
            <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>isEmailBoolean</Value>
                    <Value>True</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
        </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
        <!-- Initiate a normal logon against Azure AD B2C -->
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="NormalizePhoneNumberProfile">
    <DisplayName>extract username</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
        Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="NormalizePhoneNumber" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

with transformation as follows:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="NormalizePhoneNumber" TransformationMethod="StringReplace">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="oldValue" DataType="string" Value=" " />
        <InputParameter Id="newValue" DataType="string" Value="" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Is is possible to achieve this at all with custom policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve your requirement/transformation is to prevent users entering any whitespace characters in the `signInName` field by using regex restrictions on the claim:

```xml
      <ClaimType Id="signInName">
        <DisplayName>Sign in name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText/>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^\S+$" HelpText="Enter your email or phone number without spaces." />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
```